How to override NLog.Logger methods?
I'm using NLog.Logger all over my code. I need now to change the behaviour of logger.Info(), logger.Debug(), .... I want to do almost no changes to existing code but just to the logger factory which will return my custom logger, which inherits from Logger, with overriden Info(), Debug,... methods. But, those methods are not virtual. I thought then to implement the NLog.ILogger interface, but it has a million members to implement. The only solution I see is to create a custom class from my custom interface My.ILogger, and the implementation class will internally use NLog. This approach will obviously allow me to change the logging framework in the future, but given the time constraints, I wonder if there is another way?
Solution1
This is a better solution but still requires me to change NLog.ILogger to IMyLogger all over my code.
public interface IMyLogger
{
    void Info(string message);
    void Warn(string message);
    void Error(string message);
    void Fatal(string message);
    void Debug(string message);
    void Trace(string message);
}

public class MyLogger(string source) : IMyLogger
{
    private readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private readonly string _source = source;

    public void Info(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Info, message);
    public void Warn(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Warn, message);
    public void Error(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Error, message);
    public void Fatal(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Fatal, message);
    public void Debug(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Debug, message);
    public void Trace(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Trace, message);

    private void Log(LogLevel level, string message)
    {
        var logEvent = LogEventInfo.Create(level, null, message);
        logEvent.Properties["logSource"] = _source;
        _log.Log(logEvent);
    }
}

Solution2
Write extension methods such as Info2(this Logger...) but still will have to change Info to Info2 everywhere.
Solution3
I can inherit from NLog.Logger and override hidden memeber but that requires me to use MyLogger all over and not the base class
public class MyLogger(string source) : Logger
{
    private readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private readonly string _source = source;

    public new void Info(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Info, message);
    public new void Warn(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Warn, message);
    public new void Error(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Error, message);
    public new void Fatal(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Fatal, message);
    public new void Debug(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Debug, message);
    public new void Trace(string message) => Log(LogLevel.Trace, message);

    private void Log(LogLevel level, string message)
    {
        var logEvent = LogEventInfo.Create(level, null, message);
        logEvent.Properties["logSource"] = _source;
        _log.Log(logEvent);
    }
}

